# Connecting frontend codes on replit to your backend solidity code on vsCode

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, hardhat, ethereumjs

How do i connect my front end codes written on replit to my backend solidity code written on vsCode. When i click the mint nft button i created for the front end, the console tells me it lacks access to a functiont hat was written on vsCode

Comment: Usually you use a library, javascript has ethersjs, web3.js. For a different language you have to look for similar library.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.